# Rewrite Resurrence Function to the Idea of Dynamic Programming

Tags: time-complexity, dynamic-programming, recurrence

Can someone help me?
Rewrite the pseudo-code of Count(n) using the idea of Dynamic Programming. And determine the Time Complexity.

```
Test(n)
   If n=1 return 1
   Tn=0
   For k=1 to n-1
      Tn = Tn + Test(k) * Test(n-k)
   Return Tn
```

Comment: Have you at least read your notes about dynamic programming and complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Add [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to get a DP solution from a recursion one:

Python Code:

```
d = {}
def test(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if d.get(n) is not None:
        return d[n]
    ans = 0
    for k in range(1, n):
        ans += test(k) * test(n - k)
    d[n] = ans
    return ans
```

You can check(It's Catalan numbers indeed, learn more about it in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000108)):

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    print str(i) + ' ' + str(test(i))
```

Output:

```
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 5
5 14
6 42
7 132
8 429
9 1430
```

Time Complexity is `O(n^2)`. Because calculate a state is `O(n)`(for k from 1 to n - 1), and we need calculate n state in total to get `test(n)`.

In fact, we can achieve a O(n) solution since it's Catalan numbers...